# v3 where to get git_url?

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise, openshift-3

I am trying to clone to my local git repository.
From Mac terminal:

git clone git_url directory_to_create

In the web console, I tried to use the GitHub Webhook URL and Generic Webhook URL.  But I got this error:  The requested URL returned error: 405

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift doesn't host a Git repository for you. It relies on you having a separate hosted Git repository to pull application source code from. Alternatively, you can use a binary input build and push source code from your local system.

If you already have a deployed application how did you create it?

If it was a sample S2I application, you need to go to GitHub where the source code for that sample application was and clone it into your GitHub account. You can then check it out from your fork in your own GitHub account to your local system. You will though need to update the build configuration for the application in OpenShift to then use your fork of the original sample application.

Comment: I did follow the sample indeed.  It seemed this feature departed from v2.  The sample needed to be updated to reflect that.

Comment: If just learning and haven't done so already, you may want to read the free eBook on OpenShift available at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html as it will explain concepts.